# Image component in CQ5

Tags: jsp, aem

I am trying to use the image component from foundation its accept the image and display to the page. If I copy the component from foundation to my project folder then access the component through the page, its accept the image and show as broken on the page.

1) I have kept all my images in DAM. But the image component is looking for below path

/content/XXX/en/sah/_jcr_content/img.img.png/1366177510193.png

Can you please explain the overview of the image component.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you changed as it's hard to figure out from this very limited piece of code. But the basics of the standard image rendering are like this.

you drag the image component on your parsys, you drag an image from the content finder in the image component.

The actual rendering happens as follows. When looking at the image component, you see in image.jsp the "supposed" rendering of the image (it's written to the out stream). This image already received the request suffix of ".img.png". This is defined in the dialog of the image component in the requestSuffix property and is standard set to ".img.png"

We now have a url to the resource on the page, but sling has yet to resolve the actual image. When we go up further up in the sling resolving chain we see a img.png.jsp file inside the libs/foundation/components/page component. During the sling resolving of the image component, one ends up in this servlet because of the request suffix of .img.png. It is this servlet that is responsible for actually writing the image to the response. In the process it does put a name of "image" for the actual image.

So your final path will look like this:

```
pathToPageWithImageComponentOnIt/_jcr_content/containerComponent/image.img.png/imageSuffix.jpg
```

So in your case this would translate to:

```
/content/XXX/en/_jcr_content/par/image.img.png/1366177510193.png
```

assuming that `par` is your parsys

One cause of your image not being rendered properly could be that your custom page component does not have the foundation page component as sling:resourceSuperType which means that the img.png servlet will not be called (as it can't find it on the sling resolving chain) and thus breaking the image.

Answer (score 0):

When you have copied the image components from libs to apps directory, you must have also copied the Java file resides below that image component.
Open that Java file and rename the package and then compile it.
Your issue will be resolved.